# How to embed dropDown HTML inside ag-grid column Headers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid, ag-grid

Below is the snapshot of ag-Grid and Kendo grid.

My question is how can I embed a dropdown/html inside the ag-Grid
just like I did in kendo. I've tried to bind it with headerCellTemplate but it removes the columnName header from the grid and overwrite it with the dropDown html. I want it exactly same as in the Kendo grid.

[image: ag-Grid ui]

[image: kendo-grid UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the headerCellRenderer instead of headerCellTemplate attribute and build the following node :

1. A parent div
2. A child span with the headerName, you can get it from the params.colDe.headerName.
3. A child select element

For more details check the 2nd example of this link : https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid-header-rendering/index.php

Comment: Hey thx it worked, but if want to render the HTML inside a row how would i do it?

Comment: @Walfrat, the answer here is not helping. It would be good for readers to understand if some plunker or code is written for the answer.

Comment: @Sumit please update the answer if this is achieved, trying to find out way to append custom dropdown div on ag-Grid column headers and perform some operations.